# HTTP Error 401.0 - Unauthorized for brand new mvc4 application

Tags: security, asp.net-mvc-4

I created a brand new mvc4 web application based on Internet template. I added *filters.Add(new System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute());* to RegisterGlobalFilters method.

Login Action is marked with  [AllowAnonymous] but still when I hit F5, it generates 401 unathorized....

Comment: This should not happen. Probably some other setting interfering. Check your proxy settings.

Comment: When I change Web properties from 'use local IIS web server' to 'Use Visual Studio development server', it does not generate 401 error anymote but it renders a blank empty login page.

Comment: I had used my own AllowAuthorize attribute and removed it but still somehow it was cached. now after a while it works and shows login page.